# htaccess redirect all apart from homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need some help with HTAccess - im a complete beginner!

I have created a redirect for all traffic to a new domain name. So "/productXYZ" on the old site redirects to "/productXYZ" on the new site.

That works fine :)

However I need to stop the homepage from redirecting, as that is a landing page. (index.html)

So how do I add a condition to stop the root of the domain from redirect?

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ http://www.NEWDOMAIN.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

An alternative route would be to forward all "/index.php?" traffic, leaving the homepage alone.

Comment: Do you have more rules in your .htaccess or just the ones shown?